# Requirement of encapsulation

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, encapsulation, information-hiding

"Encapsulation is one of the most important features of OOP and is used for data protection" according to many books and websites. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) similarly states,

> Encapsulation is used to hide the values or state of a structured data object inside a class, preventing unauthorized parties' direct access to them.

But protection from what? Is it from our own ignorant selves, ensuring we dont mess up later on when programs are too long or some other factor?

Comment: Pretty much yeah.

Comment: You tagged the question for both Java and C++, which is not a good thing to do. Either the question should be language-agnostic (and I've made this change), or if you want it specific to a programming language, you should tag just this language.

Comment: If you can't see all the internal workings of a class, you can safely assume (if the programmer who created that class knows what they're doing) that you dont *need* to know the internal workings

Comment: @cameron1024 But without knowing the internal workings is there not a possibility of making some error ourselves when writing something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the motivations behind encapsulation and "information hiding" is to reduce coupling and thus reduce complexity, cyclomatic complexity to be precise, which in larger programs, can increase exponentially, and more complexity means a greater risk of bugs.  By preventing side-effects from exposed fields, you reduce the likelihood of creating bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you encapsulate data to protect it from everything that shouldn't modify it. Think about a private class in Java for example, with getters and setters. This is basic encapsulation, as you only allow to read and modify your data in a given way, while protecting it from any unwanted or unexpected modifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you make something available, then someone's going to use it, and if someone uses it, then you can't change it. Or at least you can't change it without finding, thoroughly understanding, and testing all the stuff that uses it.

If something is privately encapsulated, you only need to worry about things in the encapsulating scope, which should be small enough to understand much more easily.

Comment: Both the question and its (current) answers assume that encapsulation and information hiding are always combined. Is there no benefit to encapsulation _without_ information hiding?

Comment: @jaco0646 information hiding *enforces* what encapsulation *suggests*

Comment: Based on your answer to the OP, a suggestion has no value without enforcement. Thus, encapsulation seems to have no value in and of itself. Information hiding is all that matters.

Comment: Other developers (including your future self) may disagree with you, and they may make mistakes, but they aren't working against you.  The structure of your software is a lot about how it communicates your intent.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your insight. I wanted to investigate this pedantic point because most often encapsulation and information hiding are carelessly conflated. My own opinion is that the benefit of encapsulation is _cohesion_, which occurs regardless of whether encapsulated artifacts are hidden or exposed. Conversely, artifacts may be hidden separately (unencapsulated) with a loss of cohesion.